# Lexical Analyser In Java

Tags: java, lexer

I have been trying to write a simple lexical analyzer in java .

The File **Token.java** looks as follows :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public enum Token {

    TK_MINUS ("-"), 
    TK_PLUS ("\\+"), 
    TK_MUL ("\\*"), 
    TK_DIV ("/"), 
    TK_NOT ("~"), 
    TK_AND ("&"),  
    TK_OR ("\\|"),  
    TK_LESS ("<"),
    TK_LEG ("<="),
    TK_GT (">"),
    TK_GEQ (">="), 
    TK_EQ ("=="),
    TK_ASSIGN ("="),
    TK_OPEN ("\\("),
    TK_CLOSE ("\\)"), 
    TK_SEMI (";"), 
    TK_COMMA (","), 
    TK_KEY_DEFINE ("define"), 
    TK_KEY_AS ("as"),
    TK_KEY_IS ("is"),
    TK_KEY_IF ("if"), 
    TK_KEY_THEN ("then"), 
    TK_KEY_ELSE ("else"), 
    TK_KEY_ENDIF ("endif"),
    OPEN_BRACKET ("\\{"),
    CLOSE_BRACKET ("\\}"),
    DIFFERENT ("<>"),

    STRING ("\"[^\"]+\""),
    INTEGER ("\\d"), 
    IDENTIFIER ("\\w+");

    private final Pattern pattern;

    Token(String regex) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + regex);
    }

    int endOfMatch(String s) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

        if (m.find()) {
            return m.end();
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The Lexer is as follows : **Lexer.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Lexer {
    private StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
    private Token token;
    private String lexema;
    private boolean exausthed = false;
    private String errorMessage = "";
    private Set<Character> blankChars = new HashSet<Character>();

    public Lexer(String filePath) {
        try (Stream<String> st = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
            st.forEach(input::append);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            exausthed = true;
            errorMessage = "Could not read file: " + filePath;
            return;
        }

        blankChars.add('\r');
        blankChars.add('\n');
        blankChars.add((char) 8);
        blankChars.add((char) 9);
        blankChars.add((char) 11);
        blankChars.add((char) 12);
        blankChars.add((char) 32);

        moveAhead();
    }

    public void moveAhead() {
        if (exausthed) {
            return;
        }

        if (input.length() == 0) {
            exausthed = true;
            return;
        }

        ignoreWhiteSpaces();

        if (findNextToken()) {
            return;
        }

        exausthed = true;

        if (input.length() > 0) {
            errorMessage = "Unexpected symbol: '" + input.charAt(0) + "'";
        }
    }

    private void ignoreWhiteSpaces() {
        int charsToDelete = 0;

        while (blankChars.contains(input.charAt(charsToDelete))) {
            charsToDelete++;
        }

        if (charsToDelete > 0) {
            input.delete(0, charsToDelete);
        }
    }

    private boolean findNextToken() {
        for (Token t : Token.values()) {
            int end = t.endOfMatch(input.toString());

            if (end != -1) {
                token = t;
                lexema = input.substring(0, end);
                input.delete(0, end);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Token currentToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public String currentLexema() {
        return lexema;
    }

    public boolean isSuccessful() {
        return errorMessage.isEmpty();
    }

    public String errorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public boolean isExausthed() {
        return exausthed;
    }
}
```

And can be tested with a **Try.java** as follows :

```
public class Try {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lexer lexer = new Lexer("C:/Users/Input.txt");

        System.out.println("Lexical Analysis");
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        while (!lexer.isExausthed()) {
            System.out.printf("%-18s :  %s \n",lexer.currentLexema() , lexer.currentToken());
            lexer.moveAhead();
        }

        if (lexer.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Ok! :D");
        } else {
            System.out.println(lexer.errorMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Say the **Input.txt** has

```
define mine 
a=1000;
b=23.5;
```

The **output I expect is**

```
define : TK_KEYWORD
mine : IDENTIFIER
a : IDENTIFIER
= : TK_ASSIGN
1000 : INTEGER
; : TK_SEMI
b : IDENTIFIER
= : TK_ASSIGN
23.5 : REAL
```

But The issue I am facing is : It treats each digit like

```
1 INTEGER
0 INTEGER
0 INTEGER
0 INTEGER
```

also it doesn't recognize Real numbers . I get:

> Unexpected symbol: '.'

What are the changes needed to get the expected results?

Comment: Did you already step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Can't answer on the "real number part", because your input only mentions a TK_REAL in your output example; but there is no TK_REAL in your source code! Fix that; and I might be able to help with that as well. What I mean is: your last pieces of information about errors ... does not match the code you are showing. Create a **real** [mcve] please.

Comment: Your `REAL` pattern could be something like `(\d+)?\.\d+` to match numbers like `.1`, `23.4` or `5.678`.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. OP does not know that there is no REAL token, yet he/she expects it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your pattern to match integer is:

```
INTEGER ("\\d"),
```

That matches exactly **one** digit.

If you want more than one, go for

```
INTEGER ("\\d+"),
```

for example.

And, just for completion, the missing other pattern for floating point numbers could look like

```
REAL ("(\\d+)\\.\\d+")
```

as the comments pointed out. Or

```
REAL ("(\\d*)\\.\\d+")
```

to allow for

.23

too - if that is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks ! I am new to Java , pattern matching etc . The first issue is resolved . For the next , as you said I included **REAL ("(\\d+)\\.\\d+")** in the tokens and I got the output as                                                      23                 :  INTEGER 
.5                  :  REAL