# How to use tokenization to do lexical analysis in Java of a program in a file

Tags: java, token, tokenize

I need to do a lexical analysis of a very simple program in a file as part of a project. It was suggested to me to use tokenization to divide the lexical elements of the program. I've never used this technique and don't know how to implement it.
Tokens can be:

- a keyword like: IF, WHILE, ADD, SUB, SET, TRUE, FALSE etc ...
- a parenthesis (open or closed)
- a number
- a variable

An example of an inbound program is:

`(BLOCK (SET n 10) (SET sum 0) (WHILE (GT n 0) (BLOCK (SET sum (ADD sum n)) (SET n (SUB n 1)) (PRINT sum))))`

How do I use tokenization to recognize and divide these program elements?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067869/lexical-analyser-in-java

Comment: [Tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization)

Comment: For this case it looks like a simple FSM that tracks whether it is in a run of alphanumeric characters would suffix. Emit a token for each paren and each such run.